# How do I add a favicon

Tags: assets

I'm a newbie to Craft so apologies if this has been answered or is too simplistic for the forum but how do I change my site's favicon? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Just like you would add a regular favicon just in your head.
If you want it to be an uploaded picture I would say:

Make a global and add a field like "favicon" to it and upload your image there and display it like:

```
{% for image in favicon.fav %}
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="{{ image.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

But what I always do is just go to a favicon generator like:
http://www.favicon-generator.org/

And upload your logo and copy paste that code in your `<head>` tags in your `_layout.html` file

Comment: Thanks, Justin, will bear in mind your advice and let you know how we get on

Comment: In general I don't see any need for this to be editable through the CMS, so you could also just add the code and images to your layout template, and put the image files where they need to be on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article about creating favicons from images uploaded through the control panel:

http://craftsnippets.com/articles/adding-favicons-to-craft-cms-website?s=s